# Temperature logging program for RPi using Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have been trying to create a little program to log the CPU temperature every minute and this is what I have came up with.

```
    import os
    import time
    import datetime

    var = 1

    while var == 1:
        timesStamp = time.time()
        temperature = os.popen('vcgencme measure_temp').readline()

        date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timeStamp).strftime('%d/%m/%y    %H: %M: %S')

        text_file = open("TempLog.log")
        text_file.write(str(temp) + '    ' + str(date) + '\n')
        text.file.close()
        time.sleep(60)
```

I run and creates the log file but it only does this once rather than running once per minute and recording the results on a new line.

I am new to the RPi and python (version 3.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file in append mode.

```
text_file = open('TempLog.log', 'a')
```

`open` takes a second parameter which specifies the mode of access. Other valid values are 'r'  for read access, 'w' for write access, 'b' for binary access and 'a' if you want to write and append to the file.

You can find this documented at: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cpuTemp0=$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
cpuTemp1=$(($cpuTemp0/1000))
cpuTemp2=$(($cpuTemp0/100))
cpuTempM=$(($cpuTemp2 % $cpuTemp1))

echo CPU temp"="$cpuTemp1"."$cpuTempM"'C"
echo GPU $(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, this reads the GPU temperature, not CPU

```
temperature = os.popen('vcgencme measure_temp').readline()
```

CPU temp should be something like this

```
tFile = open('/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp')
temp = float(tFile.read())
tempC = temp/1000
```

This plus halfdan's answer should get you completely working.